# exporting a project with a library

Tags: android

I have a project that uses the githup facebook classes. I was wondering how i export my app with the facebook class as a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the facebook class an apk?
if not you should just use the export function like with every app

if the facebook classes aren't already a library go to the project preferences and then choose the android preferences and tick the checkbox "isLibrary"

Answer (score 0):

If you want simply reuse it, just create a jar and include it to your other projects.